# How to find out the type of an array?

Tags: java

Suppose i have a method `public static void aMethod(T[] items)`. How to find out if items is of type String or Int or Double? I used `instanceof` which Im not sure of.

```
public static void aMethod(T[] items)
{
  for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
  {
    if(items[i] instanceof String)
      {

       }
  }
}
```

Comment: The fact that you need to do this is a sign of code smell. What's your use case?

Answer (score 0):

Generally Class class has methods which may help, for example:

```
Object ob = new BigDecimal("30");
System.out.println(ob.getClass().getCanonicalName());
```

Result: java.math.BigDecimal

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if what you want is get the name of class...

```
items.getClass().getComponentType()
```

If you want to let different types to do different thing, use

```
instanceof
```

Answer (score 0):

Java implements generics using [type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_erasure). Therefore at runtime, the array in this case will be an `Object` array, although the objects in the array will still all (probably) be of type T - specified at compile time